# Mariadb galera cluster, unable to add another node

Tags: mysql, mariadb, percona, galera

I am trying to add third node to galera cluster using xtrabackup_v2 SST but it's keep failing error:

```
WSREP_SST: [INFO] Evaluating socat -u TCP-LISTEN:4444,reuseaddr stdio | pv -f  -i 10 -N joiner  | xbstream -x; RC=( ${PIPESTATUS[@]} ) (20150324 11:28:24.689)
   joiner:  976MB 0:00:20 [97.7MB/s] [<=>                                      ]                                                                                                                                                      [fail]
   joiner:   72GB 0:11:23 [ 108MB/s] [                        <=>              ]                                   ]
150324 11:39:47 [Note] WSREP: 0.0 (ifactory-sart-db-node-02): State transfer to 1.0 (10.10.19.3) complete.
150324 11:39:47 [Note] WSREP: Member 0.0 (ifactory-sart-db-node-02) synced with group.
WSREP_SST: [INFO] NOTE: Joiner-Recv-SST took 683 seconds (20150324 11:39:47.699)
WSREP_SST: [INFO] Preparing the backup at /data/mysql/data/ (20150324 11:39:47.710)
WSREP_SST: [INFO] Evaluating innobackupex --no-version-check  --apply-log $rebuildcmd ${DATA} &>${DATA}/innobackup.prepare.log (20150324 11:39:47.713)
WSREP_SST: [INFO] NOTE: Xtrabackup prepare stage took 16 seconds (20150324 11:40:03.532)
WSREP_SST: [INFO] Total time on joiner: 700 seconds (20150324 11:40:03.535)
WSREP_SST: [INFO] Removing the sst_in_progress file (20150324 11:40:03.538)
150324 11:40:03 [Note] WSREP: SST complete, seqno: 323482099
150324 11:40:03 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
150324 11:40:03 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
150324 11:40:03 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
150324 11:40:03 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
150324 11:40:03 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
150324 11:40:03 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
150324 11:40:03 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
150324 11:40:03 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0G
150324 11:40:04 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
150324 11:40:04 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
150324 11:40:05 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
150324 11:40:05 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
150324 11:40:05 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.20-68.0 started; log sequence number 742266833568
150324 11:40:05 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
150324 11:40:05 [ERROR] I/O error reading the header from the binary log, errno=175, io cache code=0
150324 11:40:05 [ERROR] I/O error reading the header from the binary log
150324 11:40:05 [ERROR] Can't init tc log
150324 11:40:05 [ERROR] Aborting

150324 11:40:07 [Note] WSREP: Closing send monitor...
150324 11:40:07 [Note] WSREP: Closed send monitor.
150324 11:40:07 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: terminating thread
150324 11:40:07 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: joining thread
150324 11:40:07 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: closing backend
150324 11:40:07 [Note] WSREP: view(view_id(NON_PRIM,17d6b16b-6b4a-11e4-80e3-c3f84504ece7,90) memb {
```

When I look at binary logs, it appears mariadb-bin.state file is empty, that's what causing issue.

```
alequoy@ifactory-sart-db-node-03:~$ ls -lh /data/mysql/binlog/
total 4,0K
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 37 mars  17 15:45 mariadb-bin.index
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql  0 mars  17 15:33 mariadb-bin.state
```

If I look at binlog directory on the donor server, it does not have 'mariadb-bin.state' file.

Answer (score 0):

It might be caused by this bug:
https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/MDEV-7903

Do you use a non-default log_bin location?